# Unable to run AWS CLI commands from Rundeck-No module named botocore.session

Tags: python, rundeck

From terminal all works fine, botocore is installed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
        import awscli.clidriver
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
        import botocore.session
    ImportError: No module named botocore.session

 pip install botocore
Requirement already satisfied: botocore in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from botocore)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from botocore)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from botocore)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore)
```

env:

```
SUDO_USER=ja
SUDO_UID=1000
USERNAME=root
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/ja
PWD=/tmp
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
SUDO_GID=1000
_=/bin/env
```

Comment: Does aws cli works from command line ?

Comment: Which user from console? Which user running rundeck (I guess root for rundeck...)

Comment: Do you confirm rundeck is running as root also ?

Comment: yes, it is, checked

Comment: May you share a `env && aws --version` in cli and rundeck ? (take care to redact any access key or private information in env)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get rid of error by

```
pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

then from rundeck interface:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id default_access_key
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key default_secret_key
aws configure set default.region us-west-2
```